# Trying to create image slideshow with forward and backward buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, slideshow

I've learned web developing on my own, so it's been research, trial and error. Learning how to create image slideshow on my own has been difficult and need some assistance.

I started with a "text slideshow" first to see if I can get a element/value to change. Text slideshow below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

<style>
a{text-decoration: none; color: grey;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<table>
<tr>
<td><a href = "javascript:goBackward()"><</a></td>
<td><p id = "demo"><p></td>
<td><a href = "javascript:goFoward()">></a></td>
</tr>
</table>

<script>
var i = 0;
var arr = ["one","two","three","four"];
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr[i++];

function goFoward(){
if(i >= 0 && i < 4)
 {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr[i++];} 

}

function goBackward(){
if(i > 0)
 {document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr[--i];}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried to applied the code above to "image slideshow",but can't get it to work. I need help understanding how to change images with the click of, a tag. Here is my code for image slideshow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.moveImg{text-decoration: none; color: black;}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "goBackward()" class =
"moveImg">&#60</a>
<img src = "klematis_small.jpg" alt = "faded reddish flower" id =
"myimages">
<a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "goForward()" class =
"moveImg">&#62</a>

<script>
var img = new Image();
var images = new Array();

images[0] = "klematis_small.jpg";
images[1] = "klematis2_small.jpg";
images[2] = "klematis3_small.jpg";
images[3] = "klematis4_small.jpg";

var getImg = document.getElementById("myimages");

var i = 0;
for(i = 0;i < 4;i++){
img[i].src = images[i];
}

function goForward(){
if(i >= 0 && i <= 4){
getImg.innerHTML = img[i++];
}
}

function goBackward(){
if(i > 0){
getImg.innerHTML = img[i--];
}
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: set up a JSFiddle and ill test the code

Comment: You've got loops that aren't inside functions. Would be probably be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

To change the image source path, **don't update innerHTML, you need to update src attribute**.

Instead of :

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arr[i++];
```

Use this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").src = arr[i++];
```

Also, you need to change from `innerHTML` to `src` in both forward and backward transition functions.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a bit to tidy it up, but have retained most of your code. This isnt the best way to go about doing something like this, but I am not going into all the best practices here.

Here is the HTML:

```
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>

<a href = "javascript:void(0)" class="moveImg" id="previous">&#60</a>
<div id = "myimages"><img src = "klematis_small.jpg" alt = "faded reddish flower" /></div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="moveImg" id="next">&#62</a>
```

Here is the javascript:

```
var images = [];

images[0] = {src: 'klematis1_small.jpg', alt: 'image 1 alt text'};
images[1] = {src: 'klematis2_small.jpg', alt: 'image 2 alt text'};
images[2] = {src: 'klematis3_small.jpg', alt: 'image 3 alt text'};
images[3] = {src: 'klematis4_small.jpg', alt: 'image 4 alt text'};

var getImg = document.getElementById("myimages");

var img = [];
var i = 0;
for(i = 0;i < 4;i++) {
    img[i] = '<img src="' + images[i].src + '" alt="' + images[i].alt + '" />';
}

var currentIndex = 0;
var goForward = function () {
    console.log('here' + currentIndex);
    if(currentIndex >= 0 && currentIndex < 3) {
        currentIndex++;
        getImg.innerHTML = img[currentIndex];
    }
};

var goBackward = function () {
    console.log('here' + currentIndex);
    if(currentIndex > 0){
        currentIndex--;
        getImg.innerHTML = img[currentIndex];
    }
};

document.getElementById('previous').onclick = goBackward;
document.getElementById('next').onclick = goForward;
```

And here is a working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/e9s6djq9/3/

Ideally you should move all your onclick event handling to the javascript as i have done here.

Also I have created the array using the following:

```
var images = [];
```

which is considered better practice than ussing the array declaration:

var images = new Array();

Here is an improved solution, since you have asked for a better way of writing javascript. Keep in mind though this is just a glimpse and actually writing a complete slider would involve a lot of time, hence I would recommend reading up on best practices. This is a better version than what I posted above.

https://jsfiddle.net/e9s6djq9/8/

Comment: what is the best way about doing something like this?

Comment: Well, I would be hard pressed to pick a best, but i could suggest a few good ones, depending on what exactly you want from the image slider. Here are a few points I would need to be clear on:

Comment: Sorry i went away to do a jsfiddle and forgot to update - here is my updated comment

Comment: Well, I would be hard pressed to pick a best, but i could suggest a few good ones, depending on what exactly you want from the image slider. Here are a few points I would need to be clear on: 1. Is this image slider going to have 4 static images or do you want to do something fancy like getting images from a backend, or let user upload images. I know this might be a bit advanced, but we generally use image sliders for different purposes. 2. Given its a static set of images like in this case, I would go for a component model.

Comment: Here is a sample improved version, that i could whip up in a short time: https://jsfiddle.net/e9s6djq9/8/